# MongoDB - Operations in the query

Tags: mongodb

Good morning,

I'm doing a query to get the greater than or equal to the sum of two columns records.

```
{ultimoEnvio+frecuencia <= new Date()}
```

Is it possible?

Thank you

Info collection:
[enter link description here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100844480/Mensajes%20foro/foro1.PNG)

Comment: Aggregation framework will do this

Comment: I've tried Aggregation framework, specifically with this query but I do not get it .. can you help me?

Comment: `db.c.aggregate({$project:{sum: {$add: ['$ultimoEnvio', '$frecuencia']}}, $match: {sum: {$lte: new Date()}}});` something like that

Comment: Thank you, At first it's like I had it done, but not work for me .. me always returns empty. I tried to save the date as getTime but neither works..

Comment: Can you show an example document that should apply to the aggregation?

Comment: Yes, here's an example:

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("543b71b5184d5456d259a95e"),
    "dominio" : "prueba",
    "frecuenciaEnvio" : 30,
    "ultimoEnvio" : ISODate("2014-10-13T09:00:00.000Z")
}

Comment: What's the measure of **frecuenciaEnvio**, millisecond, second, day, ... ?

Comment: It is minutes.. but I've also changed the data and I put milliseconds(1800000)..